# Maven download Eclipse artifacts via specific mirror

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus

sorry don't have enough experience with maven so question:

We have Jenkins and Nexus server. We need make maven build which is using Eclipse. As you know when we need download something from http://www.eclipse.org it redirects to one of its mirrors: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xml

On Jenkins server is firewall and only one of this mirror is whitelisted. So we need use only 1 specific mirror always.

Currently it is failing, because it redirects to not-whitelisted mirror (looks it choose it randomly):

```
[DEBUG] Resolving target definition content...
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.13.0/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.13.0/
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.13.0
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000/
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2018-07-25 17:28:40.029
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Artifact not found: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000/content.xml.xz.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:428)
```

How we can do it?

i was thinking about, specifying in **pom.xml**:

```
<repository>
  <id>eclipse-oxygen</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen</url>
</repository>
```

and in **settings.xml**:

```
<mirror>
<id>eclipse-oxygen-mirror</id>
<name>Eclipse stuff</name>
<url>url of p2 nexus repo</url>
 <layout>p2</layout>
<mirrorOf>eclipse-oxygen</mirrorOf>
```

- Configured Nexus P2 repo where is specified whitelisted mirror.

Could you please advise it that correct approach? 
Should i in the same way identify all eclipse features? (e.g. oxygen, luna, juno, indigo, etc)
like:

```
<repository>
  <id>eclipse-oxygen</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna</url>
</repository>

<repository>
  <id>eclipse-oxygen</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno</url>
</repository>
```

etc?

Thanks Christian for option disable mirroring and download directly from http://download.eclipse.org.

But which approach i need to use if i need to go via Nexus P2 repo? is approach above is correct or i need use some other way?

Answer (score 1):

you can disable mirrors using `-Dtycho.disableP2Mirrors=true` or
or via settings.xml http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#How_do_I_disable_P2_mirrors.3F

Comment: yes it will. so this url could be added to your whitelist

Comment: Thanks Christian i will try it.

But if i need to go via Nexus P2 repo, is my idea above is correct? or what approach i need to use?

Comment: Well if you mirror the p2 stuff with Nexus the you should use the urls of your nexus

Comment: so, in pom.xml i need specify real repository (download.eclipse.org) and in settings.xml then <mirror> which will go to Nexus P2 repo (which will have url of whitelisted mirrror) ?

Comment: Why not use the nexus url directly?

Comment: you mean directly in pom.xml:

    <repository>
    <id>eclipse-oxygen</id>
    <layout>p2</layout>
    <url>nexus p2 url</url>
    </repository>

and create Nexus P2 repo which will call whitelisted mirror?

Comment: Yes something like that. Don’t know how you have configured nexus. But the same should work with proxy in settings xml